# Convert unsigned byte value to float from -1 to 1

Tags: javascript, floating-point, byte

I'm not sure this is a programming question or more of a math problem, but since it's in the context of a javascript program I'm writing, I'm posting here.

I have an array of byte values from 0-255 (`UInt8Array`) representing PCM audio, that I need to convert to an array of floats from -1 to 1. This is because the Javascript Audio API buffers are `Float32Array`s. But the question is can be generalized to: how do I convert a value from 0-255 to a value from -1 to 1?

The solution I'm currently using works but looks very unelegant:
`var f = b / 127.5 - 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract it to:

```
 const mapRange = (fromStart, fromEnd) => (toStart, toEnd) => value =>
   value / (fromEnd - fromStart) * (toEnd - toStart) - fromStart + toStart;

const encodeAudio = mapRange(0, 255)/*to*/(-1, 1);

 console.log(encodeAudio(10));
```